# Xamarin iOS ObserveOrientationDidChange Landscape or Portrait

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I need to detect when the user rotate the device to Landscape orientation. I can detect when the orientation changed with the code below:

```
UIDevice.CurrentDevice.BeginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications();
this.orientationObserver = UIDevice.Notifications.ObserveOrientationDidChange(MyRotationCallback);

private void MyRotationCallback(object sender, NSNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    // Landscape or Portrait ?
}
```

It works, but I can't tell if it was changed to landscape or portrait. How I can I detect this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Check the property:

```
UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Orientation
```

#### Values:

```
LandscapeLeft
PortraitUpsideDown
LandscapeRight
Portrait
```

#### Example Setup:

In your `ViewDidLoad` (or similar):

```
Foundation.NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(new NSString("UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification"), DeviceRotated);
```

#### Delegate/Action:

```
void DeviceRotated(NSNotification notification)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Orientation);
}
```

#### Output:

```
LandscapeLeft
PortraitUpsideDown
LandscapeRight
Portrait
```